# Can TortoiseSVN be configured to search all revisions automatically when performing an svn blame?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, blame

...and yes, I know this can take several minutes.  Seriously!

I just want to right-click a file, select SVN blame and have TortoiseSVN do its thing.  I don't want to have to manually click OK every time because I never change anything in this window.

[image: Automatically select all revisions]

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is No. I just hit 'enter' since the OK button gets focus when this dialog pops up.